# Parsing Security Matrix Spreadsheet - NoneType is not Iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

Trying to Nest no's and yes's with their respective applications and services.
That way when a request comes in for a specific zone to zone sequence,  a check can be run against this logic to verify accepted requests.

I have tried calling Decision_List[Zone_Name][yes_no].update and i tried ,append when it was a list type and not a dict but there is no update method ?

```
Base_Sheet = range(5, sh.ncols)
Column_Rows = range(1, sh.nrows)

for colnum in Base_Sheet:
   Zone_Name = sh.col_values(colnum)[0]
   Zone_App_Header = {sh.col_values(4)[0]:{}}
   Zone_Svc_Header = {sh.col_values(3)[0]:{}}
   Zone_Proto_Header = {sh.col_values(2)[0]:{}}
 Zone_DestPort_Header = {sh.col_values(1)[0]: {}}
 Zone_SrcPort_Header = {sh.col_values(0)[0]: {}}


Decision_List = {Zone_Name:{}}


for rows in Column_Rows:
    app_object   = sh.col_values(4)[rows]
    svc_object   = sh.col_values(3)[rows]
    proto_object = sh.col_values(3)[rows]
    dst_object   = sh.col_values(2)[rows]
    src_object   = sh.col_values(1)[rows]
    yes_no       = sh.col_values(colnum)[rows]

    if yes_no not in Decision_List[Zone_Name]:
        Decision_List[Zone_Name][yes_no] = [app_object]
    else:
        Decision_List[Zone_Name]=[yes_no].append(app_object)
```

I would like it present info as follows

```
Decision_List{Zone_Name:{yes:[ssh, ssl, soap], no: 
                 [web-browsing,facebook]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would still like to know why i couldnt call the append method on that specific yes_no key whos value was a list.

But in the mean time, i made a work around of sorts. I created a set as the key and gave the yes_no as the value. this will allow me to pair many no type values with the keys being a set of the application, port, service, etc.. and then i can search for yes values and create additional dicts out of them for logic.

Any better ideas out there i am all ears.

```
for rownum in range(0, sh.nrows):
    #row_val is all the values in the row of cell.index[rownum]  as determined by rownum
    row_val = sh.row_values(rownum)
    col_val = sh.col_values(rownum)
    print rownum, col_val[0], col_val[1: CoR]
    header.append({col_val[0]: col_val[1: CoR]})
print header[0]['Start Port']

dec_tree = {}
count = 1
Base_Sheet = range(5, sh.ncols)
Column_Rows = range(1, sh.nrows)

for colnum in Base_Sheet:
    Zone_Name = sh.col_values(colnum)[0]
    Zone_App_Header = {sh.col_values(4)[0]:{}}
    Zone_Svc_Header = {sh.col_values(3)[0]:{}}
    Zone_Proto_Header = {sh.col_values(2)[0]:{}}
    Zone_DestPort_Header = {sh.col_values(1)[0]: {}}
    Zone_SrcPort_Header = {sh.col_values(0)[0]: {}}


    Decision_List = {Zone_Name:{}}


    for rows in Column_Rows:
        app_object   = sh.col_values(4)[rows]
        svc_object   = sh.col_values(3)[rows]
        proto_object = sh.col_values(3)[rows]
        dst_object   = sh.col_values(2)[rows]
        src_object   = sh.col_values(1)[rows]
        yes_no       = sh.col_values(colnum)[rows]



        for rule_name in Decision_List.iterkeys():
            Decision_List[Zone_Name][(app_object, svc_object, proto_object)]= yes_no
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think still a better way is to use collections.defaultdict

In this manner it will ensure that i am able to append to the specific yes_no as i had originally intended.

```
for colnum in Base_Sheet:
    Zone_Name = sh.col_values(colnum)[0]
    Zone_App_Header = {sh.col_values(4)[0]:{}}
    Zone_Svc_Header = {sh.col_values(3)[0]:{}}
    Zone_Proto_Header = {sh.col_values(2)[0]:{}}
    Zone_DestPort_Header = {sh.col_values(1)[0]: {}}
    Zone_SrcPort_Header = {sh.col_values(0)[0]: {}}


    Decision_List = {Zone_Name:defaultdict(list)}


    for rows in Column_Rows:
        app_object   = sh.col_values(4)[rows]
        svc_object   = sh.col_values(3)[rows]
        proto_object = sh.col_values(2)[rows]
        dst_object   = sh.col_values(1)[rows]
        src_object   = sh.col_values(0)[rows]
        yes_no       = sh.col_values(colnum)[rows]

        if yes_no not in Decision_List[Zone_Name]:
            Decision_List[Zone_Name][yes_no]= [app_object, svc_object, proto_object, dst_object, src_object]
        else:
            Decision_List[Zone_Name][yes_no].append([(app_object, svc_object, proto_object,dst_object, src_object)])
```

This allows me to then set the values as a set and append them as needed